# closing curl connection in gcloud pubsub php client for long polling

Tags: php, curl, connection, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using `Google\Cloud\PubSub\Connection\Rest` for pubsub connection and fetching data continuously like

```
$this->pubsub = new PubSubClient([
        'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents(base_path() . '/' . env('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')), true)
    ]);

while (true) {
    ......
     $topic = $this->pubsub->topic('topic-name);
     $subscription = $topic->subscription('subscription-name');
     $subscription->pull();
     
    .....
}
```

above code is part of a laravel command and command is being run by worker, as it is continuous process, after few hours it stops with following error.

```
   prod.CRITICAL: in popcURL error 35: Process open FD table is full
```

Apparently curl connection is in CLOSE_WAIT state, I couldn't fine anything in pubsub php [library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/tree/main/PubSub) to close connection after each pull.

Comment: GCP internally handles the `subscriptions.pull` calls. In each call it waits for a specific amount of time until it receives a message. I would suggest you to follow [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#synchronous_pull) to understand how you can `pull` messages easily. Other relevant doc [php's subscription->pull](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.185.0/pubsub/subscription?method=pull) .Your problem seems like more related to laravel or curl connections.

Comment: One more thing do you really need to create a new subscription for each iteration ?

Comment: No, I don't need new subscription every time, $topic->subscription() just creates instance. also that is true, issue is at laravel side but I am using google SDK in laravel so I am expecting a method in SDK to close connection after sending acknowledgement to gcloud.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier there is no `close connection` method available as GCP internally handles `pull` subscription calls.I am not sure whether it will work or not but can you try to create only one `instance` of subscription and use that thoroughly in your `while-loop`.You can also try use [`returnImmediately`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.185.0/pubsub/subscription?method=pull) but its a [deprecated option](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull) and not recommended .